# How to make a code for baseball runners to advance in c# language (need help)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a baseball texted based app in unity.
I want a C# unity function in my little coding that is doing this.
I have 2 variable batter and runners.
I want them to run depending on the the variable that I give to batter and runners.
So I also have baseball player number 1 through 9 coming at the plate one after the other.

So lets say the batter 4 hit the ball and run for 2 bases, that mean that all players that are on the bases already must also advance. So here the second variable that I pass runners.

So my question is, what is the code to make all these players to run and also, I have to know their number, meaning player 4 is on 2b and player 3 is on 3rd base and player 1 went to home for instance.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class runners : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string ison1b = "0";
    public string ison2b = "0";
    public string ison3b = "0";
    public string wason1b = "0";
    public string wason2b = "0";
    public string wason3b = "0";
    public string scorehome = "0";

    public string player = "0";
    public int playerlineup = 0;
    public string bases = "0";
    public int runnerbase = 0;
    public int rbiThisInning = 0;


    // Calculating whos at bat!
    string atbat()
    {


        switch (playerlineup)
        {
            case 1:
                player = "1";
                break;
            case 2:
                player = "2";
                break;
            case 3:
                player = "3";
                break;
            case 4:
                player = "4";
                break;
            case 5:
                player = "5";
                break;
            case 6:
                player = "6";
                break;
            case 7:
                player = "7";
                break;
            case 8:
                player = "8";
                break;
            case 9:
                player = "9";
                break;
        }
        return player;
    }




    public void atbatrunners()
    {

    int hitters = 8;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= hitters)
        {
            if (playerlineup > 9)
            {
                playerlineup = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                playerlineup = (playerlineup + 1);
            }


            string[,] playeronbases = new string[4,4];
            playeronbases[0, 0] = playerlineup.ToString();
            playeronbases[0, 1] = "0";


        }




            Debug.Log("At bat player No: " + atbat() + " hit a single!!");

            Debug.Log("Runner on 1B= " + ison1b + ", 2B= " + ison2b + ", 3B= " + ison3b + ", Runner to home= " + scorehome);

            Debug.Log("Total RBI this inning= " + rbiThisInning);


           
            //Debug.Log(outsAmount());


            i++;
        }

        
    }

}
```

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand your question; Im trying to so I can help you with an answer, but in any case, you can condense your code in your atbat method. Since you are looking for a number value and setting a string to a string version of the same number, you could just do something like `player = playerlineup.ToString()`.

Comment: Are you making a 2d or 3d game? Do you have your game objects placed?

Comment: @bingostew The OP mentions "texted based" so I took that to mean text-based, so it is very interesting that the OP chose to use Unity.

Comment: @rodamn sorry, kind of an interesting choice for sure. Then it would be odd to implement a "running" feature for a text-based game, unless I'm interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: The running feature is to track where the guy went after he hit the ball. So if the batter hit a double, where all the other would be. This is what i<m looking for

Answer (score 2):

Preface: I assume you are fairly new to programming--or at least to C#--based on your approach to this problem, and that's okay; please do not mistake this for condescension.

### Simulating your game & Figuring out the game's time step

It's not apparent from your code and your problem brief whether or not you have given consideration to the time-step in your game. This is important because it affects how players "run" the bases. To step back a second:

Computer "Games/simulators" can take many different approaches to simulating, and it's important to understand your game's approach. For instance, there are real-time approaches (where a second in real life is a second on the field), or a step-based approach where things happen in larger chunks of times: each step could represent one swing for the at-bat player, or each step could simulate the entirety of their turn at base.

To see why this is important, if one takes the approach of a 1-step-per-swing, a player stealing a base would have a single chance of occurring during the step, whereas 1-step-per-player-at-bat, a player stealing base would have as many chances as the at-bat player had non-foul swings at the ball. If you take a real-time approach, you would need to track each both defending and running players' positions, velocities, and check if a defending player with the baseball tags a player before they reach base.

This last approach would fully animate players transitioning from base to base, but since this is a text-based game, I imagine your aim is to update the whole game-state after each at-bat player and then display that state. Even in this case that are a lot of choices: do you just need to weigh the player's ability to reach the next base, vs. the defending players' abilities to defend against that or is each player more or less the same, and just have a random chance of success or failure?

### How to make players advance to the next base

**Simplest case**

Now let's start with the simplest possible case: assume the batter hit the ball and is moving to 1st. I would try something like this:

```
string playerAtBat = atbat();

while(IsPlayerOut(playerAtBat) == false) {
  if (DidPlayerHitARun(playerAtBat)) {
    if (IsPlayerSafe(playerAtBat)) {
      ison1b = playerAtBat;
    }
    else {
      // Handle out player, e.g. increment number of outs
    }
  }
}
```

Now, there are several big pieces missing here: `IsPlayerOut()`, `DidPlayerHitARun()`, and `IsPlayerSafe()`. I want to draw your attention to `IsPlayerSafe()`. This would be a function that accepts a player string, and returns true when the player made it safely to base, or false when he didn't. The decision mentioned a few paragraphs above would designate how the logic for this function would operate. Similarly, you would build appropriate logic for the other two functions above, accepting a player (if necessary) and returning a boolean value, true or false depending on the outcome that you simulated.

**Repeat for other bases**

Making a player move bases would be as simple as adding to their string to the next base (say, 3rd) and removing them from the previous base, e.g.:

```
isOn3b = playerString;
isOn2b = "";
```

As you might imagine, working backwards from Home back to 3rd to 2nd to 1st base (ie moving player on 3rd before player on 2nd, etc) would ensure that the following previous base is cleared for the player behind them.

### Final Thoughts

To be honest, the approach you are taking will be fairly difficult to complete a working baseball simulation, but I encourage you to stick with it, and learn what you can from making a complete game. The real improvement comes when you try again after learning from your mistakes and figuring out you could do it better.

As an alternative, I highly recommend trying Unity's Create with Code series of tutorials. This will help you quickly build to the skills to assemble some working games, and is suitable for people new to coding and/or new to Unity:
https://learn.unity.com/course/create-with-code?uv=2018.4

The tutorial (which I've done myself) will have you build five mobile-inspired games that each build on new concepts, as well as (simple) game of your own design that you design on your own. They are also really good at easing you into various C# scripting concepts.

### Bonus: How to write a functional Game Loop

In my original post above, I discussed the game's "time step," well now it's time to build that into your game. This approach is more of a **Functional programming** approach, so for those wanting to use an Object-Oriented approach or Entity-Component approach, take the idea and translate that into the approach you desire.

First we need to figure out what causes the loop to start and end, and there are many different ways games do this as mentioned before.

1. Real-time: each loop operates as quickly as possible, or possibly
   waits for the monitor to signal that it completed a screen refresh.
2. Step-based, fixed rate: This is similar to before except each loop
   occurs over a longer period, such that the game is updating at a
   speed the developer wants instead of full speed. For instance you
   might want the game to update every two seconds or five seconds.
3. Input-driven: When the user performs an action (presses a key), the
   game handles that input, simulates the response to that input.

Since I'm not sure how you envision your game playing, let's start with a fixed rate step of two seconds.

First we need a way to track what time it is now, and when the next step should occur. Fortunately Unity `MonoBehavior` handles a lot of this for us, every class that you make that has MonoBehavior has an OnUpdate() function that is called every drawn frame as explained we described in the Real-Time example.

However, we will adapt this for our less frequent update needs:

```
class GameLoop : MonoBehavior {
  public float updateDelayInSeconds;

  float nextUpdate = float.NegativeInfinity;
  void OnUpdate() {
    if (IsTimeToUpdate()) {
      GameLoopUpdate();
    }
  }

  bool IsTimeToUpdate() {
    if (Time.time >= nextUpdate) {
      nextUpdate = Time.time + updateDelayInSeconds;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void GameLoopUpdate() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, within GameLoopUpdate(), you could call your logic that you have already created to make simulate your baseball game. If you decide to change how the game updates, you can rewrite IsTimeToUpdate() to only return true when a user has pressed a key, or return true when whatever "event" causes your next simulation step to occur.

Again, don't give up, building games should be fun, but it does take require thinking and solving a lot of problems.